# Is there a way to insert innerHTML of different ids using javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

```js
var res = document.querySelectorAll("#a,#b,#c,#d")
res[0].innerHTML = "apple"
res[1].innerHTML = "bananna"
res[2].innerHTML = "orange"
res[3].innerHTML = "lemon"
```

```html
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>
<p id="c"></p>
<p id="d"></p>
```

This is running fine, but I want to be able to use something like this:

```
var res = document.querySelectorAll("#a,#b,#c,#d")[i].innerHTML = 
  {"apple","bananna","orange","lemon"}
```

Comment: Did you literally mean `"text1"`, etc., or are these meant to be placeholders for longer text?

Comment: sorry this are placeholders, not text1, i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as data is concerned, you need at minimum a way to pick a target, a piece of content for that target, and a way to tie the target and content together. One way this might be done is:

```js
const data = [
  ['#a', 'apple'],
  ['#b', 'banana'],
  ['#c', 'orange'],
  ['#d', 'lemon'],
];
```

Now that you have all the necessary data and its associations, making use of it could look like:

```js
data.forEach(([target, content]) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(target);
  if(element) element.innerHTML = content;
});
```

Reference:

- [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Do the "?." is necessary ?   As with that it is not working and without that it is working fine

Comment: @spdfEdu It's not strictly necessary. In this case, it's used to check that `.querySelector()` returned something useful before trying to assign to `.innerHTML`. The same thing could be done with an `if`/`then`. I'm surprised it doesn't work for you, though. While it's a newer feature, the main up-to-date browsers support it.

Comment: Oh, my error. I realize now why it isn't working (and that it wouldn't do what I wanted, regardless). Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop. I will highly recommend you to go over some simple [JS tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) so that you enjoy coding

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#a,#b,#c,#d")
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = `text${i + 1}`
}
```